# Regular expression to extract words from string

Tags: regex

I have a string as

str= "value 1 then perform certain action"

I need a regular expression that will make sure value and perform are present in string without being repeated.

Comment: you mean you need to check value string present in paragraph and check perform is repeated or not right?

Comment: no both should occur only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need regular expression for this simple task. use this code

```
str= "value 1 then perform certain action"
var a = str.match("value") || []
var b = str.match("perform") || []
if(a.length == 1 && b.length == 1){
    console.log("true")
}else{
    console.log("false")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the pattern as follows:

```
pattern: "value (.*) perform (.*)"
```

Comment: this doesn't ensure that value and perform are not repeated